# Is there any short way in pandas to check if every value of your matrix lie between certain values of two other "border" matrices?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Example: Checking matrix_1 must return True. And matrix_2 - False

```
import pandas as pd
low_border = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B':[2,3]})
up_border = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5,4], 'B':[4,8]})
matrix_1 = ({'A': [2,3], 'B':[3,4]})
matrix_2 = ({'A': [6,3], 'B':[3,4]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
def test(mt):
    matrix=pd.DataFrame(mt)
    for column in matrix.columns:
        matrix['verify']=pd.Series(((low_border[column] < matrix[column]) & (matrix[column] < up_border[column])), index=matrix.index)
        if False in matrix['verify'].tolist():
            return False
    return True

print(test(matrix_1))
print(test(matrix_2))
```

It will output:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Thanks! 
If there is no built-in method, that will do nicely